# Identities on the Whittaker function $W_{-\kappa,\mu}(z)$?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

As in (for example) [Magnus, W., Oberhettinger, F., Soni, R.: Formulas and Theorems for the Special Functions of Mathematical Physics, Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 52, Springer, Berlin et al. (1966); p.295], we define:

The confluent hypergeometric function is denoted by
\begin{align}\label{confluent}
{}_{1}F_{1}(a,b;z)=\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}\sum _{{j=0}}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma(a+j)}{\Gamma(b+j)} \frac{z^j}{j!}.
\end{align}
We define the Kummer's function of the second kind
\begin{align}\label{Kummer}
U\left(a, b; z\right)= \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a-b+1)} \, {}_{1}F_{1}(a,b;z)+ \frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}  z^{1-b} \, {}_{1}F_{1}(a-b+1,2-b;z).
\end{align}
By $W_{\kappa,\mu}(z)$ we denote the Whittaker function given by
\begin{align}\label{Whittaker}
W_{\kappa,\mu}(z)  &= e^{-z/2} \, z^{\mu+\tfrac{1}{2}}U\left(\mu-\kappa+\frac{1}{2}, 1+2\mu; z\right).
\end{align}

Following the identities on the Whittaker function [Magnus:; p.299]
$$W_{\kappa,\mu}(z)  = W_{\kappa,-\mu}(z).$$
Now, I would like to know what is the relation between $W_{\kappa,\mu}(z)$ and  $W_{-\kappa,\mu}(z)$.

Any reference. thank you in advance.

Comment: See the Wolfram functions site, e.g. https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/WhittakerM/16/01/01/. If you align your notation with theirs, and the site doesn’t show an identity of the kind you want, then probably no such identity is known.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.14.E30